# widget previewImage attribute on API 8

Tags: android

I have defined a widget provider xml in my app as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp" 
    android:updatePeriodMillis="43200000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_widget_on"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

But Eclipse shows me a warning :

```
Attribute "previewImage" is only used in API level 11 and higher (current min is 8)
```

So, to remove this warning while supporting API 8, i define a custom namespace and use that for the previewImage attribute as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp" 
    android:updatePeriodMillis="43200000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    myApp:previewImage="@drawable/ic_widget_on"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

But now Eclipse shows me the error :

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'previewImage' in package 'com.myDomain.myApp'
```

Usually this solution works for other newly introduced attributes when using the support library. But why is it not working for `previewImage`? Doesn't the support library support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But Eclipse shows me a warning

That warning should not affect anything of note. Preview images were not used by the platform at all prior to API Level 11.

> Usually this solution for other newly introduced attributes when using the support library.

App widgets are not part of the support library.

Comment: So this widget will not visible on phones with API 8? I tried running an AVD with API 8 and i could not figure out where the widgets are even listed. On API 11, there is a `+` on top right corner of the screen that shows the widgets.

Comment: @faizal: "So this widget will not visible on phones with API 8?" -- no, the app widget should be available. However, the widget picker on API Level 1 through 10 did not use preview images. "I tried running an AVD with API 8 and i could not figure out where the widgets are even listed" -- long press on the home screen background, IIRC.